# can i connect this to the header?

Tags: gpio, cable

I recently discoverd a very old agenda coumputing vr3 pocket computer and wondered if it was possible to connect it to my pi. But i need to use a cable and have no idea what it is. I'm wondering if it is possible to connect to the headers? (likely not) or, what kind of cable is it
[image]

Comment: That looks like a serial cable as for connecting it to the GPIO this should get you started http://www.davidhunt.ie/add-a-9-pin-serial-port-to-your-raspberry-pi-in-10-minutes/ you can also get a USB to serial adapter like this http://www.amazon.com/Tripp-Lite-USA-19HS-High-Speed-supports/dp/B0000VYJRY/ref=pd_sim_147_8?ie=UTF8&dpID=41%2BS537DgrL&dpSrc=sims&preST=_AC_UL160_SR160%2C160_&refRID=13DCJAXB0T0FX7ZPM3T2 You can probably do a search for the product manual and verify that it is a serial cable

Comment: @SteveRobillard I think that RPi's built-in UART will be just fine here, no need for USB-to-UART bridge chip

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin you are probably correct but with an unknown and proprietary device I would err on the side of caution and add a little insurance for the Pi. also maintaining a good connection with jumper wires can present a hard to track down bug

Comment: @SteveRobillard Agreed!

Comment: @steverobillard can i connect it without an adapter straight to the pins?

Comment: just by sticking jumpers in the holes?

Comment: You may be able to, that is what @AlexeyVesnin was referring to re: built in UART. But also note my comments above about insurance and bugs.

Comment: @SteveRobillard ok but do you know what pins on the pi corespond to holes in the cable?

Comment: i found out what each hole does but i'm not sure which pins they match up with.

Comment: RS-232 uses much higher voltage than 3V, it will burn Raspberry in case of direct connection!